# Using an html link to input value into django view

Tags: python, django, svg

Pretty new to Django still. I have a map that the user will click on a country. I want that link to add the country name to:

URL:

```
url(r'^country/(?P<name>\w+)' , 'wiki.views.country',
        name = 'wiki_country'),
```

Then the country view will open. I want to do it this way so that I can create a dynamic country view that can populate based on the name of the country, rather than individual pages served for each country. The view looks like this so far:

```
def country(request, name):
    country = Country.objects.get(name=name)
    return render_to_response("wiki/country.html")  , {'country' : country})
```

I don't know how to take the map, or even just a text hyperlink and pass the name into the URL.

Answer (score 1):

use name url patterns. 
Add named urls with argument in 'href' in templates.

`<a href="{% url 'wiki_country' country_object.name %}"> {% country_object.name %} </a>`

'*country_object.name*' is your input argument for country function.

[Django Docs reference of named urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)